# Where can I add functions to WordPress, not related to the theme?

Tags: wordpress

Here's the situation: There's a WordPress plugin in place that enables a mobile-friendly theme if a mobile User Agent is found (with the usual details and logic, not important).

This mobile theme is copied from the plugin directory, into another, and overwritten when updates to the plugin come out.

I need to provide some extra custom functions for the theme, but don't want to put *all* of the code directly in the mobile plugin/theme, because it may get overwritten.

I think the best thing might be to put my special/custom functions into their own plugin, and deal with the theme-specific changes as they come up - that way there's less to diff/compare when updates come out.

What do you think is the best approach with something like this? Is there a safe alternative to creating my own plugin, where I can store some custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a wordpress [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), so that if the parent theme gets updated all your changes remain intact. From the above link:

> ...the functions.php of a child theme does not override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s file.)

That should allow you to do what you need to do.

Comment: IN this case, the theme in question is being loaded programmatically, and so I don't have the opportunity to choose a child theme. Thus, I would still need to edit the plugin, pointing it to the child theme... unless there's some method I'm not thinking of? Generally, you would definitely be right. This plugin is a bit strange, but I think we're stuck with it for now.

Comment: Ah, that makes since. I came across [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-dependencies/) while searching, but in your case it may be better just to create your own custom plugin that hooks into the mobile plugin.